# rand() produces 1 number too high?

Tags: c++, random, srand

It is  my understanding that `rand() % a + b` will return numbers between a and b including both a and b. I must be misunderstanding this though, because when I run the code below `int r` will return 2, 3, or 4. I, of course, am expecting it to return 2 or 3. I'm calling `srand(time(NULL));` in main and I'm using 
`#include <time.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`
Am I missing something?

```
    int r = (rand() % 3) + 2;
    if (r ==2)
        g_fan.draw(r); // skin == 2
    else
        g_fan.draw(1 + r); //skin == 4
```

Comment: `X%3` is in set (0,1,2) so adding 2 will make it in the set (2,3,4)

Comment: This is why [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) is so nice.

Comment: Thank you, I've never quite got this until you worded it like that. I've always seen the example `rand() % 100 + 1` and just always thought of that as `rand () % max + min = random between min and max with both including`. I totally get it now. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It is my understanding that `rand() % a + b` will return numbers between `a` and `b` including both `a` and `b`.

No. It will result in a number between `b` and `(a+b-1)`, both including.

Range of values of `rand() % a` is `0` and `a-1`, both including.

Hence, the range of values of `rand() % a + b` is `b` and `(a-1+b)`, both including.

To get random values between `a` and `b`, both including, use:

```
auto interval = (b-a+1);
auto result = a + rand() % interval;
```

Answer (score 0):

let `num` be any number you get by calling rand() and if you do `%` with 3 , there is a possibility of getting one of these number 0, 1, 2.

therefore you are getting 2 ,3,  4  for :

```
 int r = (rand() % 3) + 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int r = (rand() % 3) + 2;
```

The `rand() % 3` will return a number between 0 and 2. When you add t2 to each number, that means it will return 2 to 4. The `rand() % a`function in general returns a value form 0 to `a - 1`. When you do `rand() % a + b`, then the resulting value will range from `0 + b` to `a - 1 + b`.

To get a value between 2 and 3, use:

```
int r = (rand() % 2) + 2;
```

The folloing `rand()` function gives a number from `0` to `2 - 1`, which is `1`. When you add 2 to each number, you get a range of `0 + 2`, which is 2, to `2 - 1 + 2`, which is 3.